# In VB.NET how do I get a textbox to only allow one decimal point, < 3NUMBERS before it, and only 1NUMBER after it?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

As the question suggests, I need a textbox to only allow one decimal point in it, less than three numbers before it, and only one number after it.

I've compiled this code so far.

```vb
Private Sub TextBox14_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox14.KeyPress
    Dim keyChar = e.KeyChar

    If Char.IsControl(keyChar) Then
        'Allow all control characters.
    ElseIf Char.IsDigit(keyChar) OrElse keyChar = "."c Then
        Dim text = Me.TextBox14.Text
        Dim selectionStart = Me.TextBox14.SelectionStart
        Dim selectionLength = Me.TextBox14.SelectionLength

        text = text.Substring(0, selectionStart) & keyChar & text.Substring(selectionStart + selectionLength)

        If Integer.TryParse(text, New Integer) AndAlso text.Length > 3 Then
            'Reject an integer that is longer than 16 digits.
            e.Handled = True
        ElseIf Double.TryParse(text, New Double) AndAlso text.IndexOf("."c) < text.Length - 3 Then
            'Reject a real number with two many decimal places.
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    Else
        'Reject all other characters.
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The biggest issue I'm getting is that the user can put in multiple decimal points and then basically all the rules I created go away. Additionally, the user is not able to set 2 numbers before the decimal point when I want them to.

Comment: You should learn Regular Expressions. They are tailor made for this.

Comment: I did a year ago but I forgot them

Comment: Would something like ^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$ work? How would I implement that into my code?

Comment: Why is this tagged C#?

Comment: That depends on which programming language you end up using (your tags seem to go for all of them). C# has a Regex-Class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is there maybe a line of code I could add such that only digits can be entered if a decimal point already exists in the textbox.text?

Comment: Regex or a masked textbox, if you don't want to deal with patterns.

Comment: If you don't want to go either of those routes, there's always the option of abusing the IsNumeric function in combination with what your validation is.  If it has 2 decimal points, it will return false, since it will not be a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using my head.

Private Sub TextBox11_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox11.KeyPress
        'What is allowed to be typed in sale price textbox
        Dim keyChar = e.KeyChar

```
    If Char.IsControl(keyChar) Then
        'Allow all control characters.
    ElseIf Char.IsDigit(keyChar) OrElse keyChar = "."c Then
        Dim text = Me.TextBox11.Text
        Dim selectionStart = Me.TextBox11.SelectionStart
        Dim selectionLength = Me.TextBox11.SelectionLength

        text = text.Substring(0, selectionStart) & keyChar & text.Substring(selectionStart + selectionLength)
        If TextBox11.Text.Contains("."c) Then
            'Forbids a user from entering in two decimal places
            If keyChar = "."c Then
                e.Handled = True
            ElseIf text.Length - text.IndexOf("."c) > 3 Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        Else 'no decimal point currently in textbox
            If text.Length > 5 And keyChar = ("."c) Then 'Allows only a "." to be written 
                e.Handled = False
            ElseIf text.Length > 5 Then ' Numbers before decimal point above 99,999
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If
    Else
        'Reject all other characters for this textbox.
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```